# Server always responds 200 with curl, but gives error messages when accessed in browser

Tags: api, post, curl

I'm trying to communicate with a third party server using curl.

The authentication system is as follows:

1. Use credentials to ask for cookie
2. Set cookie
3. Make requests

This in itself has not been a problem and I am able to make requests etc, but whatever I send the server always responds 200 even if i send an invalid data format.  If i put the same url in the browser it returns error messages about the invalid format.

Does anyone know why this might be?  Thanks in advance,

```
function go($url,$postvars=null)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie_.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookie_.txt');    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($postvars));
            $postfields = http_build_query($postvars);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postfields);    
     curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch); 
 }

 go($url,$login_array);  //login=>'',pass=>''
 go($url,$some_request_array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very likely possibility is a bug in the server code that means it sends 200 statuses with its error messages. Hence while in the browser it'll be an error message, because that's what is in the body, it'll still be "successful". Put an intercept (firebug network, fiddler, etc) on the browser access and see what the status is.

If this is the case you've two options:

1. Get the party responsible for the server to fix it.
2. Parse for the error message yourself, and then treat it as an error condition.

Comment: Hi Jon.  Thanks a lot.  That's the problem.  But why does curl not show me the error message with the 200 response though?

Comment: Beats me, I was supposing that it might be, though whether you'd see it or not would depend no just what you did with the response, and likely move further from HTTP (which I know about) and into the workings of curl (which I don't know about).